# Python 3 hosting

Tags: python, hosting, python-3.x, cherrypy

I am looking for companies hosting websites developed in Python 3 and CherryPy.  Webfaction looks good, but it is limited to Linux servers, and my site has been designed and tested under Windows.  Can anyone summarise (or point me to) the changes I will have to make to my code in order to get it to run under Linux?

I guess if I want to keep my code unchanged I may have to go for a VPS (virtual private server).  I will have more control over what I install, but it's a lot more expensive.  Has anyone had any experience of this setup with Python?

Comment: Are you using anything likely to be Windows-specific?  It's hard for us to provide detailed advice without seeing the code, beyond obvious things like "avoid modules containing the word win."  CherryPy and Python should insulate you from *most* cross-platform issues.  I would consider just purchasing a month worth of Linux hosting, and doing some testing.

Comment: You could always download [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org) and a Linux distribution and try out your code in that environment, locally.

Comment: @Alan it's hard to image wanting to use Windows for a live server when you are not using a .Net framework IMHO.

Comment: Matthew - No, there is nothing Windows specific, but sometimes the code looks for files in a specified path (eg. \dev\python\config\myconfigfile.txt), which I am guessing would fail under Linux.  Is it simply a matter of reversing the backslashes to forward slashes?  Alternatively is there a test for if Linux: do this else: do that ? Regards.

Comment: birryree - thanks for the suggestion.  I've looked at the Virtualbox site and I am still not clear how it works.  Would I need to have the Linux installed on another disk partition?  Does Virtualbox enable me to run stuff on Linux while viewing it from within Windows?  Regards.

Comment: Josh - you are right - I don't really care whether the site runs under Linux or Windows, and as there are many more Linux hosts out there (and they are less expensive), that wins it for me.  But first I need to know what to look out for in my code which might cause it to fall-over.  Regards.

Comment: For the most part, you won't notice anything, especially if you're using no OS-dependant functionality (Which you said you weren't). As you mentioned, the file paths will change, so yes that would need to be updated in your source. For Virtual Box, it allows you to run another virtual computer - with whatever you want on it (EG, Linux). This will allow you to test everything in linux whilst staying on your windows installation.

Comment: @Matthew: isn't Python3 wsgi still somewhat broken?

Comment: @Paulo, it's definitely in flux.  There's some information at [WSGI for Python 3](http://wsgi.org/wsgi/Python_3).

Comment: @TyrantWave - Thanks for that.  Is there a Python command for testing which OS is running (eg. if linux, use '/', else use '\')?  Re. VirtualBox, does this mean that I will have to install Linux on another partition of the same HDD (can't use 2 HDDs on my laptop)?  Regards.

Comment: @Paulo - It's not so much broken as undefined, but PEP 3333 aims to resolve that.  Meanwhile I am using CherryPy 3.2 with Python 3, and have had no serious problems (yet :-) ).  Regards.

Comment: @Alan Harris Reid: thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Alan Harris Reid: `import os; print os.name` tells you the name of the OS.

Comment: @TyrantWave - Thanks for the OS tip.  I've just tried it on my Windows 7 machine and it returns 'nt'!!  Still, I suppose Microsoft will get its act together one day and return more meaningful os data :-(  Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can buy inexpensive VPS hosting and configure it the way you like, Python and all. This way is preferable if you want to tweak other parts of the stack later, e.g. switch to a different WSGI implementation.

Also you can use Amazon EC2 similarly, as @meimimo [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965114/python-3-hosting/5004743#5004743); it is free to start.

Comment: Amazon looks more like a cloud application provider.  How does that differ from a VPS?  Any recommendations for a reliable and inexpensive VPS?  (I'm in the UK, but I don't suppose it matters where it is).  Regards

Comment: Note: I have very vague idea of EC2 services. On EC2, you can easily add or remove resources as needed by your load, potentially paying less and withstanding spikes well. But there are some limitations on storage. On a VPS, you have more or less fixed amount of resources, but less limitations, it's more like a traditional piece of hardware. Sorry, can't recommend any VPS provider; the one I use is Russian, and I never tried others so far.

Comment: it comes with python 2.6.8 not python 3

Comment: @eyaler: both a VPS or a EC2 instance give you root access. You can compile and install whatever you want. Python 3 may not be one apt-get away, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use amazon EC2 and configure your OS as you wish.
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/